# How to link a MySQL Table with a binary key into Access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

In MS Access I've created a linked table via ODBC to a MySQL table with a binary(16) primary key column (UUID). MS Access only shows the first row, all other rows have #deleted entries. I guess the reason for this is the binary field. I've checked the ODBC driver properties without success. Do you have a solution to this problem?

**Details:** I'm using Access 2010 64 bit and "MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver". Opening the linked table looks like this:

[image: linked_table]

The MySQL table has following Definition (reduced):

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default          | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| LNEr          | binary(16)    | NO   | PRI |                  |       |
| Datum         | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL             |       |
| StatNr        | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL             |       |
```

MS Access generates following Definition:

[image: Access_definition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a [updateable VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html) to the table. The view displays every column but the primary key `LNEr` is converted to a string with the [HEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function:

```
CREATE VIEW v_ereignisse AS SELECT HEX(LNEr) AS LNEr, Datum, StatNr, ...
```

In MS Access instead of creating a link to the table I created a link to the view. Because the view has no primary key, the "table link manager" asks for selecting one, this (of course) is the string version of `LNEr`.